# Tune Dual Boot with Windows 10 on separate drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I used various Ubuntu distribution via VirtualBox on my Windows 10 host and as I'm quite happy with **Lubuntu 16.04.1**, I wanted to give it a try and install it as my 2nd OS besides the existing Windows 10 (which has been upgraded from Windows 7, if that makes any difference). Therefore I got an **extra** SSD (sdc), and already installed it there (which gave me troubles too, because the installer didn't detect the new SSD so I had to care for partitions manually), but *I'm not sure if everything is as it should be*.

I *am* able to boot into Windows 10 *and* Lubuntu, but there are some (minor?) problems.

## Problems

1. Sometimes when I boot the computer, I end up in a grub command line instead of the menu to choose between Windows and Linux. When this happens, I reboot, check the boot order in BIOS (UEFI?), see that Ubuntu should be booted before Linux, exit without saving (and reboot), and then it takes me to grub's selection screen as expected.
2. In BIOS (UEFI?) there are 2 boot entries for ubuntu, but I cannot find any difference between those.
3. I tried to run Boot-Repair, but it asks me to deactivate Secure Boot, which I don't want to (and shouldn't be needed as far as I've found out).

After all,  I still want to be able to boot into Windows 10, preferably without grub (but not a must), when I boot the SSD with Windows 10 (sdb) (or when the extra SSD with Lubuntu (sdc) is disconnected) and I want be able to choose between Windows 10 and Lubuntu on startup when I boot the SSD with Lubuntu (sdc), which will be the default. I also want to keep UEFI and Secure Boot activated.

It'd be no problem to reinstall/remove Lubuntu or even remove all partitions from sdc, but the Windows 10 installation (sdb+sda) must stay functional.

## Hard Drives (via GParted)

1. sda: 500 GB HDD, msdos (existing, for Windows 10 user data and other data)

   - sda1: one big NTFS partition

     - flags: boot
     - Windows cannot run without this one because all user data is stored here (via symlink). This is because long time ago I only had a very small SSD and set it up that only the OS, but not the user directories are on the SSD. When I upgraded to the bigger SSD (sdb), I just cloned the small one and increased sdb3's partition size.
2. sdb: 250 GB SSD, gpt (existing, for Windows 10)

   - sbd1: 100 MB EFI fat32, EFI system partition, mounted to /boot/efi

     - flags: boot, esp
   - sbd2: 128 MB unknown, Microsoft reserved partition

     - flags: msftres
   - sbd3: ~ 240 GB NTFS, Windows 10 is installed here

     - flags: msftdata
   - sdb4: 450 MB NTFS, no more information what it is used for

     - flags: hidden, diag
3. sdc: 250 GB SSD, gpt (new, for Lubuntu)

   - sdc1: ~240 GB ext4, Lubuntu 16.04.1 is installed here

     - no flags
   - sdc2: 4 GB swap

     - no flags

## Boot-Info (via Boot-Repair)

What bothers me here is that it finds a boot loader only on sda and not sdb where I expected it to be. But this might be because sda has a *msdos* partition table and the other two have *gpt*, but I don't know.

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
```

If there is need for *Drive/Partition Info* or any other info from Boot-Repair, I can update this post.

## Other system information

- Motherboard: Asus H87M-E
- Memory: 16 GB RAM

Comment: You've got both a legacy boot and a UEFI boot set up, which do you use?  You still can't boot Windows through grub when secure boot is enabled (bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464 ), you need to use the EFI menu.