# Windows 10 does not start after ubuntu-mate has been booted (Updated)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

### Update

I tried ubuntu-mate 16.10 these days and its installer asked me if I wanted to remove some legacy boot records from my EFI configuration (which I confirmed). This gave me hope that it'd actually solve my problems here. Well, nope. :(

### Situation

I had some spare time and installed Windows 10 and ubuntu-mate 16.10  (before: Lubuntu 16.10) on two different SSDs with only one of them connected to the motherboard during installation to ensure clean configuration of both of them (so my [old dual boot problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812196/tune-dual-boot-with-windows-10-on-separate-drives) shouldn't have any relevance anymore).

Of course I don't want to smash `ESC`, `F8` and/or `DEL` rapidly during boot to select my boot drive (and therefore OS) on startup "manually", so I added Windows 10 (`/dev/sda2`) to ubuntu-mate's GRUB configuration (`/dev/sdb1`) with the following command (output **updated**):

```
markus@ubuntu-mate:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-22-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Everything is (and should stay) UEFI and Secure Boot is (and should stay) activated. **Update:** This time I did not connect my old HDD (used for simple data storage), to reduce all possible sources of problems.

### What does and doesn't work

- I *can **not*** boot Windows 10 via GRUB when ubuntu-mate ran before because of some Secure Boot problems (see photo). This is **the main problem** I have.
- I *can* boot ubuntu-mate via GRUB without any problems
- I *can* boot Windows 10 when I select it on computer startup "manually"
- I *can* boot Windows 10 when I disconnect the SSD with ubuntu-mate and GRUB installed
- I *can* boot Windows 10 via GRUB when Windows 10 ran before
- I *can* boot Windows 10 via GRUB when ubuntu-mate ran before and I've then visited system setup (UEFI) and exited without any changes
- I *can **not*** boot Windows 10 via GRUB when I disconnect the SSD with Windows 10, but not because it isn't found, but because I get the same Secure Boot errors.

So for me it seems that starting/running ubuntu-mate somehow damages something in GRUB's or UEFI configuration for Windows 10 **or** that starting Windows 10 "manually" or entering UEFI does something silently which gets reverted by ubuntu-mate later.

### Additional question

How do I *see* if my OSs are installed in different modes (as commented in my [old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812196/tune-dual-boot-with-windows-10-on-separate-drives) and in this one as well)?

### GRUB's version

```
markus@ubuntu-mate:~$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu11
```

### Photo

[Secure Boot Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEqIQ.jpg)

### Boot Info Summary (updated)

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

ubuntu-mate-vg-root: ___________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.10
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

ubuntu-mate-vg-swap_1: _________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
```

Comment: Actually your old dual boot problem are one and the same and the comment in your other question is still valid: You can't dual boot via Grub with OSes installed in different modes.